# How to know if an object is dynamic in AS3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, oop, dynamic

In Action Script 3, you can write a class that defines a dynamic object (MovieClip and Object are two examples), this objects can be modified in run-time. What I want to know if is there some way (in run-time, of course) to know if certain object is dynamic or not.

PS: Without making something like this:

```
function isDynamic(object) {
    try {
        object.newProperty = 'someValue'
    } catch (e) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CookieOfFortune has the right idea, but unfortunately the code itself has problems, isDynamic is an attribute, and the returned value will be a XMLList with a value of a String that reflects a true or false value, not a child node that directly returns a Boolean. It should look more like this:

```
function isDynamic(object) : Boolean
{
    var type:XML = describeType(object);
    return type.@isDynamic.toString() == "true";
}
```

Comment: But what if you want to test for dynamic in order to avoid a call to describeType.. sigh.

Answer (score 3):

You can use describeType from flash.utils to describe the object in XML form. Here's the reference to the API: [flash.utils.describeType](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/langref/flash/utils/package.html#describeType())

```
function isDynamic(object) {
    var type:XML = describeType(object);
    if (type.@isDynamic == "true") return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "if (type.isDynamic) return true". I think this can be made by just "return type.isDynamic"

Answer (score 3):

Be careful!

Anytime you want to use the describeType() function, *please* *please* *please* use the variation:

```
import mx.utils.DescribeTypeCache;
var typeDesc:XML = DescribeTypeCache.describeType(object).typeDescription;
```

Performance of making repeated calls to the runtime reflective machinery will absolutely *suck*. That's why Adobe invented the DescribeTypeCache class.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old post, but I'll add an option for those future searchers.

AS3 has a built in way of doing this:

```
mx.utils.ObjectUtil.isDynamicObject(yourObject);
```

Read more about it [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#isDynamicObject%28%29).

Comment: As we can see in http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.as  isDynamicObject uses try...catch