# Create a dynamic class from an embedded swf symbol

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

I am trying to create a dynamic class from a symbol in an embedded swf, basically I need to be able to add arbitrarily named properties for some exciting math, but it appears the only way is to create a dynamic class.

```
[Bindable]
[Embed(source='ExternalAssets/Assets.swf', symbol="assetName")]
private var AssetNameObject:Class;

var obj:Object = new AssetNameObject();
obj.someDifferentProperty = someValue;
```

This is throwing an error of "cannot add property 'someDifferentProperty' to object"

Is this even possible?

Comment: *edit*  I have found a method to do this by creating a MovieClip object and adding my object to it.  the MovieClip object being a dynamic object allowed the addition of a arbitrary property but it creates an extra level of objects and i am hoping to keep the total # down if possible.

Comment: you should explain what exactly you want or what you are trying to achieve. If you do so, people can give alternative solutions. Like wvxvw said, its not possible to do what you are trying. if your requirement is just to add a property then maybe but may you want to change your code slightly like this 
**var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.asset = new AssetNameObject(); 
obj.someDifferentProperty = someValue;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. You have already found the only way of doing it which is to add a movieclip as its parent and attaching the dynamic properties to the movieclip.

If you could explain in more detail what exactly you are trying to achieve.. maybe someone can suggest an alternate way of doing it without the dynamism.

The best perhaps you can do is to check whether the object is dynamic which can be achieved as given by this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748685/how-to-know-if-an-object-is-dynamic-in-as3).